# Логика валидации формы

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

Вопрос достаточно обширный, но ответ найти я не смогу.

К примеру, я имею сервис, который публикует некие новости разных людей за определенную сумму. То есть любой человек может зайти на сервис и опубликовать новость за деньги, без регистрации на самом сервисе.

Логика построения данного приложения:

1. Человек заходит на страницу с формой заполнения новости.
2. Заполняет, нажимает submit, происходит валидация. Если все данные верны, то мы заносим нашу новость в MongoDB, где хранятся все новости, которые не оплачены, но уже заполнены.
3. После `insert in mongo` мы возвращаем `_id` поста и переходим на `new_news/_id:` (`_id` - заполненная новость из MongoDB), то есть переходим на страницу с оплатой новости.
4. Я использую Stripe. Человек заполняет данные с кредитной картой и т.д., нажимает "оплата". Если она проходит, то мы переносим новость из "временной коллекции", где хранятся неоплаченные новости, в коллекцию, где хранятся новости для публикации.

Любой может перейти на `new_news/_id:` и оплатить чью-то новость, но тут проблемы я не вижу, так как, даже имея id новости, редактировать он не может, так как пользователей в принципе нет, а без пакетов `insecure` и `autopublish` в `meteor`.

Верно ли я мыслю?

Comment: "Вопрос в том, верно ли я мыслю ?" какой то странный вопрос, ответ - смотря чего хотите добиться. Как насчет редактирования своей оплаченной новости ?

Comment: нет, данной функции нету, но было бы интересно посмотреть как это реализовывается, но на данный момент я не могу сделать впринципе элементарные действия которые я описал, и поэтому вот такой вышел вопрос

Comment: так а что именно то не получается ? Какой пункт ?

Comment: Хороший вопрос, дело в том, что я не понимаю до конца верны ли мои пункты, всё ли надо делать так, а на практике интеграция со stripe, хоть документация читал  и 2 туториала , но всё же непонятна механика токенов и как всё это куртиться

Comment: вы пытаетесь понять как Stripe работает изнутри ? зачем ? снаружи все просто на первый взгляд - вы формируете токен с помощью библиотеки от Stripe, отправляете его себе на сервер с данными карты, потом спрашивает у stripe валидна ли карта, используя этот токен и если валидна - записываете что товар оплачен.

Comment: то есть как я понял из ваших слов, мы делаем токен из данных карты и тд. отправляем его на страйп если карта проходит и деньги снимаются на возращают что то вроде ОК, если нет то FALSE, верно ?

Comment: нет не из данных карты, страйп вам сам токен присылает (т.е. не вам а клиенту)

Answer (score 1):

Подумайте над тем, как пользователь который, решил оплатить чью-то новость сможет это сделать при (например) краше браузера или какой-либо ошибке? Как он снова найдет то, что хотел? Ваша модель без пользователей проста только на первый взгляд, на самом деле это может добавить вам много проблем в будущем.

Я бы сделал так:

```
—Регистрировал бы пользователей по email и паролю, при этом письмо подтверждения не отправлял бы(ведь вам важна скорость доступа пользователя к нужной информации).
```

После авторизации вы сможете дать пользователям:

```
1. Добавлять новости в избранное для послед. оплаты
2. Разрешить создателю новости редактировать ее
3. Создатель новости будет иметь возможность отслеживать все операции, связанные с сего материалами.
```